Framer motion not changing display value
I have an animation on my next.js app used on a mobile menu. The animation controls the opening and closing. I've made it using Framer motion and it worked perfectly until now. Basically, when I close the menu, I set display from "flex" to "none" on the container, but for some reason, display stays on "flex". Let me know if anyone knows how to fix this.
Here are the variants:
  const containerVariants = {
    open: { opacity: 1, display: "flex" },
    closing: { opacity: 0, display: "none" },
    finished: { display: "none", opacity: 0 },
  };

Here is the element:
<motion.main
      animate={props.open ? "open" : animationFinished ? "finished" : "closing"}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3, type: "tween" }}
      onAnimationComplete={() => setAnimationFinished(true)}
      variants={containerVariants}
      className={styles.container}
    >

And yes, props.open is false and animationFinished is true when I close the menu, the opacity even changes to 0, but the display stays at "flex". Also, in the scss file the display is set to "none", framer-motion variable overrides it and sets it to "flex".
For context, I used the same exact code multiple times and it worked perfectly on other apps.
